# Unity Multiple displays not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.4.1f1 personal edition and working on Windows standalone build. I want to use multiple displays in my game. I have 2 cameras and set the target display of one camera to display 1 and target display of second camera to display 2.

Also, I have activated the display but **Display.displays.Length is always one** on editor as well as on build.

So it does not display anything on the second screen. What should I do to display on second screen?

Answer (score 5):

You need to activate each additional display in code with `Display.Activate`.

See [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html) where it says:

> The best time to activate additional displays is upon creating a new
>   Scene. A good way to do this is to attach a script component to the
>   default Camera. Make sure you call Display.Activate only once during
>   the startup. You may find it helpful to create a small initial scene
>   to test it.

And from the example, in the `Start()` Method:

```
if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
    Display.displays[1].Activate();
if (Display.displays.Length > 2)
    Display.displays[2].Activate();
```

Note: Once a monitor has been activated, you cannot deactivate it.

Comment: Yes i have done this step but as Display.displays.Length is returning 1 it never activates the second display.

Comment: @Nain Perhaps update your question to make it more clear that you've already done this. I know you've written "I have activated the display", but you can make it more clear by providing a code example.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is actually bug. Don't waste your time trying to fix it. Go to *Help* --> *Report a Bug...* then report the problem. There are many bug reports open for this problem but it's a good idea to file for another one to remind them that this is still not fixed.

Here are bug reports on this. Unity claims to have fixed this on some of them but that's not true because I was able to reproduce this problem with my computer with Unity 5.6. [*Bug Report 1*](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/display-dot-displays-dot-length-outputs-wrong-display-count-in-editor-console), [*Bug Report 2*](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/display-dot-displays-always-shows-one-display) and [*Bug Report 3*](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/osx-display-dot-displays-dot-length-doesnt-identify-the-second-monitor-connected-to-a-mac).

Comment: I wouldn't create a new bug report for the same issue. I would upvote the bug reports that already exist.

Comment: @PJvG You can up-vote for bug fixes but you need points. Most people ran out of points(I did). You have two options: Create new account or file for a new bug then let Unity sort it out. Sometimes, it is a different problem that is causing the new problem. Other times, it is the-same problem and Unity will mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I see. There's a third option though: you can remove your votes from other issues you deem less important. If you go [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/users/votes) you can see what you've voted on. Still, it would be nice if there was a way to get more points.

Comment: My votes are all serious bug reports so removing them isn't really helpful.  Also, I think you can only remove votes if the issue if not solved. If the issue is solved, the points are gone and you can't get it back. I may be wrong on this but I failed to re-take my points after some of the bugs were fixed. Will login to that link you posted today and see if this is true.

Answer (score 4):

**This bug was in unity 5.4.1 i have tested with unity 5.6.1f1 and above unity multiple displays works just fine there is no need of expanding screen or setting parameters just need to activate the displays and set the target display property of camera**

Unity documentation is a bit ambiguous about this feature.

Also Display.displays.Length always return 1 in editor mode but in build it works fine.

I have found a solution to this problem reference to post http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/309819/getting-unity-to-render-across-multiple-monitors.html. That is we have to call **Screen.SetResolution(sum of width of all displays , height, false);** the false is because we do not want to render in fullscreen mode. This is because unity does not creates multiple windows it only create one window we have to extend it to match the resolution of multiple displays.

Activate the aditional displays by calling Activate() and aslo set the setparams to give the each display a starting value. I worked it out for 3 displays.

```
if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
{
 //display 0 is set by default
    Display.displays[1].Activate();
    Display.displays[1].SetParams(Width of display 1,height of display 1,starting x for display 1,starting y for display 1);
}
if (Display.displays.Length > 2)
{
    Display.displays[2].Activate();
    Display.displays[2].SetParams(Width of display 2,height of display 2,starting x for display 2,starting y for display 2);
}
```

In the build setting set **'Display Resolution Dialog' to 'Disabled'** make sure **'Default Is Full Screen' is NOT checked.**

Create the build and then there is a final step run the exe wtih **-popupwindow or -multidisplay** command line argument.

If it still not worked open your screen resolution dialog and verify the positioning of monitors.

It works good but it produces **fish eye effect**.

Comment: so this means that your statement " but Display.displays.Length is always one on editor as well as on **build**" is false. Oh well, it is still returning `null` in both Editor and Build for me and I think that's a bug. It still a bug if it is returning null in your Editor.

Comment: yes  you are right i checked it later and realized its just returning 1 on editor.

Comment: Ooops. Made a big typo. When I say null, I meant 1. Looks like you got it.